# Adding AJAX call on each page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So, I'm new to AJAX and I'm not sure how I will do this, but I have three different pages and I would like to add AJAX call to all of them and everything inside of those files.

I guess the page would start with something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        $('').load('target.php');
    );
});
```

Not sure if that's a start or not?
I'm quite a newbie, so if I forgot any information please tell me and I will try to edit the first post.

```
I would like to add the call when you click a menu.
EDIT:
<?php

echo "

      <li><a href='gestbookk.php'>Woodland</a></li>
         <li><a href='fileupload.php'>Hem</a></li>
         <li><a href='laddaupp.php'>Mountains</a></li>


";

?>
```

This one is included to all pages.So the AJAX call starts when clicking on one of the menu links.

Comment: include this javascript in all the pages..

Comment: Is it so simple? No more php required?

Comment: just give it a try...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**in that case you need something more or less like this:**

```
  $(document).ready(function()
 {
   $('li a').click(function(){
        $.get($(this).prop('href'), function(data){
            $('#CONTENTHERE').html(data);
        });
        return false;
    });
 });
```

$('') => Doesnt make that much sense, neither does the set interval(Jquery allso has build in timers)

this would prolly be something you are looking for:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $.get('target.php', function(data){
//we are done add this to our body
    $(body).append(data);
  });
  $.get('target2.php', function(data){
//we are done add this to our body
    $(body).append(data);
  });
  $.get('target3.php', function(data){
//we are done add this to our body
    $(body).append(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: I updated my first post.
So when I navigate by using the menu I want to do the call. Sorry, forgot to add that!

Comment: My menu is included to all pages. Do I write the code inside the extended php menu file or do I call the function at each page?

Comment: Thanks man! But do I add that code inside the menu.php or inside the page?
#CONTENTHERE, I want to add the whole page. Both php and html codes. So do I add the div-content-holder ID to that or?

Comment: This javascript will: add a javascript handler to the links.
When they click it it will send a ajax call the the href of the link.
So it will change your ordanary click/load into a ajax call.

Make a div with id='CONTENTHERE' (or change them in the code and in html) and it should work

Comment: that code just needs to be somewhere on your page.
Doesn't matter where it is as long as it's there once :)

Comment: Works super! Thanks alot! Have a nive weekend;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     setInterval(function(){
     $('').load('target.php');

       }, 1000);

   });
 </script>
```

Comment: So if I want to add this to the menu: <?php

echo "

      <li><a href='gestbookk.php'>Woodland</a></li>
         <li><a href='fileupload.php'>Hem</a></li>
         <li><a href='laddaupp.php'>Mountains</a></li>
        

";

?>
which is included to all three pages.